Azure DevOps Pipelines: deploy Java projects as maven dependencies for other projects
I have to create Azure DevOps pipelines for multiple Java maven projects that previously had no CI/CD process.
All the projects are on the same Azure DevOps organization and are stored in Azure Repos.
Some projects include others as maven dependencies: how do I deploy them to a maven repository in azure?
I tried creating an artifact, linking it to the pom (in  and ) and it works if I run mvn deploy from my machine because I have set the setting.xml in my .m2 folder with the token I've created.
Do I have to add the token to the pipeline? If yes, how? If no, what's the best solution?
Thank you for any advice

You don't have to authenticate against the PAT to restore the maven pacakges published in Azure Artifacts feed during pipeline build.
Since you have published the maven package to Azure Artifacts feed and added dependency to install that package in the pom.xml file of your project,
（My pom.xml to restore sample package JavaAppDemoHelloAlvin from Azure Artifacts feed ProjectScopeFeed-Maven）
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxxxxx.javaapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>JavaAppDemoHelloAlvin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
...


You may test to add the MavenAuthenticate@0 task which will provide credentials for Azure Artifacts feeds.
See MavenAuthenticate@0 - Maven Authenticate v0 task | Microsoft Learn for more details.
steps:
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: 'ProjectScopeFeed-Maven'
- task: Maven@4
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'install'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false



